# libgdx changing the texture on a pre textured model

Tags: opengl, model, libgdx, textures

I've exported a model from blender but I want some instances to use a different texture

```
       if (x % 2 == 0) {
            shipInstance.materials.clear();
            shipInstance.materials.add(new Material());
            shipInstance.materials.get(0).set(new TextureAttribute(TextureAttribute.Diffuse, enemyTexture));
```

unfortunately doesn't work!

In a similar way I want to be able to change things like shininess and smoothing
(I'm guessing you can change things like this that are using the default shader?)

I've also (later) tried this...

```
Material mat = shipInstance.materials.get(m);
for (Iterator<Attribute> ai = mat.iterator(); ai.hasNext();){
    Attribute att=ai.next();
    if (att.type==TextureAttribute.Diffuse) {
       ((TextureAttribute)att).textureDescription.set(enemyTexture,TextureFilter.Linear,TextureFilter.Linear,TextureWrap.ClampToEdge,TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);
    }
}
```

amongst other things...

Comment: What type is ShipInstance of?

Comment: think it was a model instance but that was nearly 4 years ago...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

argh!

```
for(int m=0;m<shipInstance.materials.size;m++) {
    Material mat = shipInstance.materials.get(m);
    for (Iterator<Attribute> ai = mat.iterator(); ai.hasNext();){
        Attribute att=ai.next();                        
        if (att.type==TextureAttribute.Diffuse) {
            ((TextureAttribute)att).textureDescription.set(enemyTexture,TextureFilter.Linear,TextureFilter.Linear,TextureWrap.ClampToEdge,TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);
        }
    }
}
```

My mistake was to subtract 1 from materials.size !!! (the last material in the model happened to be the most obvious one, it was in many cases when I tried different things probably working (accept for the last material) DoH!!!